# Trying to get Xdebug session initiated in a docker inside a VM to reach my remote computer

Tags: docker, xdebug

I have a docker running my PHP app.
This docker needs to run inside a VM in a remote datacenter.
I work from a computer that can connect to the mentioned VM.

My intention is to have the Xdebug session that is initiated inside the docker reach my computer (more precisely my PHPStorm).

Both docker and the VM are running Centos (company approved/installed images).
The development computer is OSx.

I am able to use ssh remote forward (aka: tunnel) to forward any requests from the VM to my computer.

I want to either:
 - be able to open a tunnel from my computer directly to the docker container in the VM
 - or be able to continue the current tunnel in from the VM to the docker.

Have found no way to do the first option and have ran into a lot of issues trying to do the second.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You *should* be able to use current SSH tunnel. It's Xdebug that connects to IDE and not other way around ... so if you establish a SSH tunnel, it will listen on a specific port in your VM. Then you just need Xdebug to connect from inside Docker container back to host OS (which is your VM) .. where it will connect to port controlled by SSH and it should forward it further to your local computer.

Comment: Debugging via SSH: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/remote-debugging-via-ssh-tunnel.html. I suggest to have the same Docker image installed on your local computer first and ensure that Xdebug is properly configured there first (as it will be just a single layer). Once it's working -- do similar config on real image (where you have 2nd layer on top: SSH tunnel). P.S. never did anything like that myself so no detailed instructions from me.